# Can't find the possible buffer overflow in a piece of code

Tags: c, buffer-overflow

I've been writing the following bit of code, and someone had informed me that it runs of the risk of having a buffer overflow.

Now admittedly my knowledge of buffer overflows may be not be as robust as I would like, but I thought that a buffer overflow is when the data being written will not fit within the bounderies of the buffer and will spill over to adjacent memory location.

I assumed that the problem may be related to the fread, that it wouldn't be a safe function to use, but reading through the documentation doesn't seem to tell me that its unsafe like say strcpy() is compared to strncpy(). So I'm rather uncertain on where the problem could be located or how to handle it. And also if anyone has any suggestions on where I can go (or what book to read) that would help expand my knowledge on this subject or other vulnerability weaknesses, I would be appreciative.

```
bool readLong(FILE *f, long *n)
{
    unsigned char *ptr,tmp;

    if (fread(n,8,1,f) != 1)
        return false;

    ptr = (unsigned char *)n;
    tmp = ptr[0];
    ptr[0] = ptr[7];
    ptr[7] = tmp;
    tmp = ptr[1];
    ptr[1] = ptr[6];
    ptr[6] = tmp;
    tmp = ptr[2];
    ptr[2] = ptr[5];
    ptr[5] = tmp;
    tmp = ptr[3];
    ptr[3] = ptr[4];
    ptr[4] = tmp;

    return true;
}
```

Comment: To begin with, what makes you so sure `long` is 8 bytes on your system?

Comment: We don't know what will be passed as `f` and `n`. If one-byte buffers are passed to them, there will be buffer overflow because multi-byte read and written will be performed to them.

Comment: `if (fread(n,sizeof *n,1,f) != 1)` is a first improvement.  Rest of code should not assume 8 bytes for a `long`.  And should not assume a certain endian.

Comment: Did you mean `&n`?

Comment: @stark, no because it’s already a pointer.

Comment: @Daniel In that case we have no idea whether n points to a single long, an array of longs or NULL.  We need to see how it is called.

Comment: All that needs to be checked is that it isn’t NULL.  All we care about is that, at that location, there is **a** long.

Answer (score 2):

You're attempting to `fread` 8 bytes into a `long`.  While a `long` **might** be 8 bytes on your system, this is by no means guaranteed.  If it's only 4 bytes long, then you're definitely corrupting the surrounding memory.  This also comes up when you assign a value to `ptr[7]`.

What you should be doing is `fread(n,sizeof(*n),1,f)`.  You can also replace `ptr[7]` with `ptr[sizeof(long)-1]`.

Comment: Not only `ptr[7]` but also `ptr[6]`, `ptr[5]`, and `ptr[4]` are out-of-range with 4-byte `long`.

Comment: Oh, yeah.  Thanks for the catch.